# Laravel 8 - Can't get authenticated from API route to display web route (Auth Sanctum)

Tags: php, laravel

I just started working in Laravel and ran into an issue with Sanctum Authentication. I have a website setup using blades that shows the front-end site and forms. I use web.php to route the front-end pages and for authentication for an account section. I am using jQuery to send requests to the API (api.php) for registration, login, and verification. The API sends over the credentials and creates a Bearer token which I store in local storage for later API requests. After login I redirect the user to the /account page which is guarded with auth. The issue is that web.php doesn't find the authentication token set from the api and redirects the user back to the login page. Here is some code showing how the site is setup, please let me know if I missed something in my files:

**api.php - this is the api route to create the login token. This is in the ajax request.**

```
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
```

**web.php - this is the account view that needs to be secure and get the api token before displaying (currently not getting the token correctly)**

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/account',[UserController::class, 'index']);
});
```

**AuthController.php - this is the logic for creating the token and sending it back via the api request. I store this in local storage for other api calls**

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if (!Auth::attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Invalid login details'
            ], 401);
        }

        $user = User::where('email', $request['email'])->firstOrFail();

        $user->tokens()->delete();

        $token = $user->createToken('token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
            'result' => 'success',
            'token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'Bearer',
            ]);
    }
```

**UserController.php - this is the basic account view being returned after the token has been authenticated**

```
public function index() {

        return view('account/dashboard', ['title' => 'Account Dashboard | Exclusive Member | Mint Auction']);

    }
```

**auth.php - this shows how my guards are setup inside of the Auth config file**

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out...

I was sending the wrong CRSF Token in my ajax request so it kept coming back as mismatched.

I also adjusted the following code:

**web.php - web routes (made auth:web)**

```
Route::middleware('auth:web')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/account',[UserController::class, 'index']);
});
```

**Kernel.php - I added middleware for the api middlewaregroup**

```
'api' => [
            \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            'throttle:api',
        ],
```